# Using sessions to preserve <td> values in PHP

Tags: php, html, session, html-table

I have a table that I generate columns for using a for loop like so:

```
echo <table>
echo "<tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < $NUM_COLUMNS; $i++){
   echo "<td>" . $resultArr[$i] . "</td>";
}   
echo </tr>
```

But when I reload my page, all the values in those columns are lost and I would like to keep them. I've used sessions before with input boxes where I can specify an input's name and value, but how would I accomplish the same thing with a  tag?

Comment: `echoing` a session variable is not so different from `echoing` a common variable in php. Though session variables are array in nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite simply save the whole array inside the session.

```
$_SESSION['resultArr'] = $resultArr;
```

Then use it later on in the `for` loop like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < $NUM_COLUMNS; $i++)
    echo "<td>".$_SESSION['resultArr'][$i]."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do it that way:

```
// top of PHP file
session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");   // (optional) hold'em for an hour in entire domain
session_start();
```

...copy result array into session array (once or when you want to change them)

```
$_SESSION["resultArr"] = $resultArr;
```

...then use always that session array instead

```
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < $NUM_COLUMNS; $i++) {
   echo "<td>".$_SESSION["resultArr"][$i]."</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```